# ListView covering the entire screen

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm writing a code for a chat app. I decided to put the messages in a ListView and then have a textView to let my user type the message he wants to send.
The problem is that my ListView covers the entire screen even if it only contains 2/3 elements, as for debug purposes. In my Android studio design pan for my xml file I do see the TextBox but, when I try to launch on the phisical device (in this case, a 10inch Samsung tablet), the TextBox doesn't exist.

This is my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_messages"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/list_messages" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/id_edit_text_message"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="Message"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_weight="10" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

And this is my ListView element, if it matters...

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:id="@+id/list_item_message" />
```

Comment: On your ListView element replace `android:layout_height="match_parent"` with `android:layout_height="0"`

Answer (score 0):

Use a `RelativeLayout` as root element instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_messages"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/id_edit_text_message"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:text="Message"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
             />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:text="Send"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use this approach

XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_messages"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/list_messages" >

        <EditText android:id="@+id/id_edit_text_message"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:text="Message"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:layout_weight="10" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:text="Send"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is from the Android Studio Layout design:
[image: this is from the Android Studio Layout design]

This is from the device nexus 7 tablet:
[image: this is from the device nexus 7 tablet]